# About __attribute__ support in different C compilers

Tags: c

I found that a lot of compilers just do not support `__attribute__`.

```
#if defined (__GNUC__)

short xxxyyy[aaa_SIZE]__attribute__ ((aligned (32)));

#endif
```

or even

```
#ifndef __attribute__(x)

#define __attribute__(x)

#endif
```

As far as I know, GNUC is the only one supporting this `__attribute__` — is that correct?
And is it reasonable general practice to use macros like above?

Is there any C standard that supports this?
Or is there any better approach?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: The [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler supports `__attribute__` for GCC compatibility.

Comment: In case of alignment specifically, C has supported alignof/alignas specifically since C11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New C standard ([C23](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) — working draft) added attributes in `[[attribute]]` format. It is portable.  They are already a part of C++ since C++11.

Example:

```
[[noreturn]] void f(void) {
abort(); // ok
}
```

All older C standards do not have it and they are compiler extensions. Do not use them unless you ***really*** need them (for example writing low-level hardware stuff).

If such a program has to be compiled by many compilers you will need plenty `#if`s.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The attribute syntax has been part of C++ already since C++11, `[[noreturn]]` specifically as well.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the answer I was expecting.

Comment: @user17732522 — I sit corrected.  Thanks.